# Getting a parseerror from jQuery $.ajax post return using jsonp from Trakt.tv api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

Working with the Trakt.tv API. It looks like I'm sending valid json as I'm able to authenticate but the return I receive is a parse error.

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: 
http://api.trakt.tv/recommendations/shows/myApiKeyCompleteNumbers?callback=jQuery111000155555475132972_1397674204444&{%22username%22:%22userName%22,%22password%22:%22mySha1PassComplete%22}&_=1397674207093

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The return says:

```
Disallowed Key Characters.
```

I'm using:
jQuery 1.11.0

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function success(data) {
        alert('data: ' + data);
    }

    var traktUser = 'myUserName';
    var traktHash = 'mySha1Password';
    var traktApi = 'myApiKey';
    var data = {
        'username': traktUser,
        'password': traktHash
    };
    var postData = JSON.stringify(data);
    var apiUrl = 'http://api.trakt.tv/recommendations/shows/' + traktApi;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl,
        data: postData,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
    }).
    done(success);

}); //document ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a POST request using JSONP, jQuery is ignoring the POST instruction and making a GET request.

Your data is being placed in the query string and is not properly URL Encoded.

The server is responding with an HTML document containing an error message instead of a JavaScript script formatted according to JSONP rules.

---

It looks like the API you are trying to use does not support JSONP at all. Since you are passing your own user credentials in the request, this makes sense. JSONP is a hack to work around the Same Origin Policy that is implemented by browsers (these days we can use CORS instead) and there is no point in using it unless you want end user browsers to access the API directly. Since end user browsers couldn't access it without being given your username and password, it doesn't seem likely to be intended to be used that way.

Process the data from the API on your server instead.

Comment: But then how do I make a cross domain request? If I don't use jsonp I get 401 unauthorized @Quentin

Comment: You ask the person providing the API what mechanisms they have in place to support cross origin requests. (As mentioned in the answer, it looks like they do not expect you to give your credentials to your users so their browsers can make the requests directly).